Android Studio : Change Variable from another Class in MainActiviy don't effect the Canvas
I create a class "Properties":
class Properties {
    var x = 200f
}

In the second class "Canvas" I can change the variable "p.x" and the Canvas shows the correct Coordinates on myCanvas.drawCircle(p.x, 100, 10f, myPaint):
val p = Properties()

class Canvas(context: Context?, attrs: AttributeSet) : View(context, attrs) {
  ...
  p.x = 600f

  override fun onDraw(myCanvas : Canvas) {
    myCanvas.drawCircle(p.x, 100, 10f, myPaint)
  }
}

But if I try to change the p.x in MainActivity.kt nothing happens in the Canvas (the value p.x will be changed correctly)
lateinit var getCanvasClassID : View
val p = Properties()

override fun onCreate(savedInstanceState: Bundle?) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState)
    enableEdgeToEdge()
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_main)

    getCanvasClassID = findViewById(R.id.canvasView)

    p.x = 700f
    getCanvasClassID.invalidate()
}


You have named your own class Canvas?

Yes. All working correct, only when I try to change "p.x" in "MainActivity.kt", the Circle in the Canvas not move. If I use "p.x" for example "p.x = 500f" in the "Canvas" class in TouchEvent and use getCanvasClassID.invalidate() in MainActivity.kt it works (the Circle moved).

You shouldn't name your class Canvas, because that is what is causing the issue. Try with a different name first

Yes that was just an example, but even with different name it don’t works. @Abdo21 explain what the problem is in the post bellow.

I think these are totally different Properties objects in your classes.

I don’t understand exactly what you mean with different properties in the classes?

You need to make sure that the Canvas class is aware of the changes to the Properties object made in MainActivity. Currently, the Canvas class uses a separate instance of Properties, so changes made in MainActivity do not reflect in the Canvas class.
One way to achieve this is by passing the same Properties instance to the Canvas class and using it within the onDraw method.
class Canvas(context: Context, attrs: AttributeSet?) : View(context, attrs) {

    var properties: Properties = Properties()
        set(value) {
            field = value
            invalidate()
        }

    override fun onDraw(myCanvas: android.graphics.Canvas) {

        myCanvas.drawCircle(properties.x, 100f, 10f, myPaint)
    }
}

In the caller side you can used it like this:
lateinit var getCanvasClassID : View
val p = Properties()
override fun onCreate(savedInstanceState: Bundle?) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState)
    enableEdgeToEdge()
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_main)

    getCanvasClassID = findViewById(R.id.canvasView)

    p.x = 700f
    getCanvasClassID.properties = p
}


Thanks, but I can't access to "getCanvasClassID.properties" in "MainActivity.kt". "getCanvasClassID." shows me only the Canvas functions and variables.

@JCss Change the line lateinit var getCanvasClassID : View to lateinit var getCanvasClassID : Canvas to ensure the variable is of the correct type.

if I change lateinit var getCanvasClassID : View to lateinit var getCanvasClassID : Canvas I get an Error for getCanvasClassID = findViewById(R.id.canvasView) > Type mismatch: inferred type is View! but Canvas! was expected
